# Como evitar o estouro de buffer em aplicação Assembly (nasm) simples?

Tags: assembly, buffer-overflow

Estou querendo evitar a escrita fora da aplicação devido o excesso de buffer, mas não sei como. O aplicativo é simples: mostra uma mensagem que pede ao usuário para digitar algo, em seguida pega esse dado digitado e mostra na tela. Porém, quando o usuário ultrapassa o limite estabelecido ocorre o estouro.

**Código:**

```
section .data
    userMsg db 'Digite um número : '
    lenUserMsg equ $ - userMsg

    dispMsg db 'O número digitado foi : '
    lenDispMsg equ $ - dispMsg

section .bss
    num resb 5

section .text
    global main

main:
    ;User prompt
    mov edx, lenUserMsg
    mov ecx, userMsg
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h

    ;Lendo e guaradando os dados do usuário
    mov eax, 3
    mov ebx, 2
    mov ecx, num
    mov edx, 5
    ;5 bytes (1 para sinal) da informação
    int 80h

    ;Mostra a mensagem 'O número digitado foi: '
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, dispMsg
    mov edx, lenDispMsg
    int 80h

    ;Mostra o número digitado
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, num
    mov edx, 5
    int 80h

    ;Saindo
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 80h
```

**Exemplo de execução:**

Tudo ocorre bem para o limite de bytes -- aqui eu digito 1234:

```
rafael@Gauss:~ $ ./entrada 
Digite um número: 1234
O número digitado foi: 1234
```

Aqui com estouro de buffer, inclusive rodando um comando do sistema operacional -- neste exemplo eu digito 12345ls para rodar o ls (comando de mostrar arquivos no linux) no estouro:

```
rafael@Gauss:~ $ ./entrada 
Digite um número: 12345ls
O número digitado foi: 12345rafael@Gauss:~ $ ls
entrada  entrada.asm  entrada.o
```

Como faço -- de uma forma simples -- para que isso não ocorra e ao mesmo tempo manter o limite de bytes ? Isso é possível?

Comment: Eu entendo que existe uma falha de segurança neste programa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu programa está absolutamente correto e a saída estranha que você está vendo é de fato a saída esperada. Observe:

```
rafael@Gauss:~ $ ./entrada 
Digite um número: 12345ls
O número digitado foi: 12345rafael@Gauss:~ $ ls
entrada  entrada.asm  entrada.o
```

Primeiro você executa o programa, ele então escreve `"Digite um número: "` e aguarda. Você então escreve `"12345ls\n"` e aperta <kbd>Enter</kbd>. O programa lê então 5 caracteres tal como foi programado para fazer. Então o programa obtêm `"12345"` e deixa `"ls\n"` intocado.

Por fim, o programa escreve: `"O número digitado foi: 12345"` e termina. Repare que não há quebra de linha no final. Tendo terminado o programa o seu terminal segue adiante e escreve `"rafael@Gauss:~ $ "`, então lê a entrada procurando por comandos, encontra `"ls\n"`. Um comando perfeitamente válido e com um <kbd>Enter</kbd> apertado no final. O terminal vai executar o comando gerando `"entrada  entrada.asm  entrada.o"`.

Ou seja, não tem nada aqui de errado, está tudo acontecendo como deveria acontecer e seu programa é completamente seguro contra buffer overflow. Ele tem um buffer de 5 caracteres e sempre lê exatamente 5 caracteres.

Experimente esse comando: `echo 12345ls | ./entrada` para dar uma entrada apenas e exclusivamente para o programa.

Comment: Mas buffer overflow não seria isso? Uma entrada que deveria ser para aplicação, quando excede o limite escreve no sistema operacional? Se realmete essa aplicação estiver ok, como faço para ela limpar esse buffer?

Comment: Não. Buffer overflow é quando a aplicação não limita o que pode ser lido e salva 10 caracteres em uma array de 5 elementos. Ou seja: sobrescrever a memória da própria aplicação. Não há nada que deva fazer nesse caso, o que está ocorrendo é perfeitamente normal. Mas se quiser basta ficar lendo caracteres em loop e descartando eles até que zero caracteres sejam lidos.

Comment: Obrigado, fiquei um pouco mais tranquilo! Vou dar uma estudada mais profunda mais tarde.